# Populate dropbox in html with values of mysqli database using php

Tags: php, html, dropdown

The database has a list of storeids and I want that to be populated in my dropdown list.The following code seems right but only yes is getting displayed in the list.

```
 Store id:
<select>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT storeid from store");
    while($list=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $storeid=$list['storeid'];
    echo '<option value="' . $storeid . '">' . $storeid . '</option>';
     }    
?>
</select><br>
```

Comment: you are opening and closing `<select>` tag twice, look at your HTML output

Comment: You don't need nested html <SELECT> tags, Just put "yes" option in front of recordset loop. But, it seems that here your db connection or PHP engine does not work.

Comment: db connection is given through database.php file.

Answer (score 0):

remove second select from code.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT storeid from store";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <select>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $storeid = $row['storeid'];
            echo '<option value="' . $storeid . '">' . $storeid . '</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

this is my code which run in local

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "yourdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from store";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <select>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $storeid = $row['storeid'];
            echo '<option value="' . $storeid . '">' . $storeid . '</option>';
        } ?>
    </select>
<?php } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

then output is :
[image]

Comment: Only yes remains in the dropdown list.

Comment: so if you want to two dropdown then check second option

Comment: I wanted only only dropdown. Used the 'yes' to check the direct method of populating will work or not.That works but from the database the store id s aren't getting populated.

Comment: you want only one select and first time yes only populate then when select yes then next option will add?

Comment: Didn't get you sir.

Comment: I tried your second option but yes is being displayed. The store id values aren't getting retrieved.

Comment: do you check now?

Comment: just wait , i find problem

Comment: yes. after u updated to three code snippet. I tried the second. Only 'yes' is being displayed.

Comment: again check my second option if db connect ok then it will work

Comment: yes and '.$storeid.' is getting displayed. Also 'query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>' part is getting displayed before dropbox.

Comment: so everything ok?

Comment: no.. the '.$storeid.' is getting displayed. i want the values of storeid from the database.

Comment: That row and list variables which you just changed I had already changed it when executing and checked. But still yes and '.$storeid.' is getting displayed.Also 'query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>' part is getting displayed before dropbox.

Comment: ok give me your full code here . it will work so something wrong here